# React.js, onclick handler not changing state of the component

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am developing an app using node.js and react.js. I am trying to change the state of a component using an onclickhandler. The state of the component is not changing once it is rendered on the browser. However , if I try to do an alert in the onclickhandler its working.What might be the issue?
Here is the component that I'm trying to render :

```
var Server = module.exports = React.createClass({

     getInitialState: function() {
        return {

           readOnly:"readOnly",

        }  
        },


    onButtonClick: function() {
       this.setState({readOnly: ""});

    },

    render: function render() {

        return (
            <Layout {...this.props}>
                <div id='index'>
                    <h1>Hello {this.props.name}!</h1>
                    <button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Click Me</button>
                    <input readOnly={this.state.readOnly} />
                    <br/>
                    <a href='/'>Click to go to an react-router rendered view</a>
                </div>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: <button onClick={this.onButtonClick.bind(this)}>Click Me</button>

Comment: That doesnt work too

Answer (score 0):

You need to set readOnly true or fasle.

```
   onButtonClick: function() {
       this.setState({readOnly: true or false});

    }
```

It should work.

Comment: Is it a rendering issue?..it seems the onclick handler is not attached to the component

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you could add or remove an attribute to an element

```
var Example = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            readOnly: true,
        }
    },


    onButtonClick: function () {
        this.setState({readOnly: !this.state.readOnly});

    },

    render: function render() {

        return (
            <div {...this.props}>
                <div id='index'>
                    <h1>Hello {this.props.name}!</h1>
                    <button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Click Me</button>
                    <input {...(this.state.readOnly) ? {readOnly: 'readOnly'} : {}} />
                    <br/>
                    <a href='/'>Click to go to an react-router rendered view</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Or a simpler version could be  <input readOnly={this.state.readOnly} />

Comment: Hey..I did the same thing as you can see from my code.It doesnt work!

Comment: react considers readOnly, disabled and a few attributes as special attributes and use boolean attributes to manage them on form controls. Either you could use the code i've pasted to manually add or remove attributes or use <input readOnly={this.state.readOnly} />. But in both cases i've used boolean instead of a string to indicate the state.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer input value is editable only if u click the button otherwise the value of the input is not editable. This is one of the most simple way to achieve this...

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Sample extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
   inputValue:"praveen"
  }

  this.valueChange = this.valueChange.bind(this);
 }

 valueChange(e){
  this.setState({inputValue: e.target.value})
 }
 render(){
  return(
   <div>
    <input type="text" value={this.state.inputValue } />
    <button type="button"  onClick={this.valueChange}>Edit</button>
   </div>

  )
 }
}

export default Sample;

ReactDOM.render(
 
 <Sample />,
 
 document.getElementById('root')
 );
```